# Почему sizeof(long) - 4 байта при компиляции под 64-битную систему?

Tags: c++, winapi, память

Проблема состоит в общем и целом вот в чём:

Я сейчас учусь работать с памятью на "более низком" уровне, чем указатели и ссылки.
т.е. работать в с++ конкретно с адресами и значениями памяти на этих адресах.

структура `DWORD` определена как `typedef unsigned long DWORD`.
Ну и получаю я память из функции WinApi таким вот костыльным образом:

```cpp
    DWORD base = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    LONG_PTR pointerAddr = *(LONG_PTR*)(0x7FF600000000 + base + pointerOffset);
```

Даже если получать из `(LONG_PTR)GetModuleHandle(NULL);` то всё равно возвращается значение размером в 4 байта, т.е. `DWORD`

Я понимаю что стандартно `long` должен быть не меньше чем 32 бита, но почему же при компиляции под 64-битные системы он не конкретно 64 бита?

[image: sizeof(DWORD)] [image: метод компиляции]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18901080/why-is-the-sizeofint-sizeoflong

Comment: А нигде не сказано, что он обязан быть именно 64 бита. 64 разряда - для адреса, а не для целых чисел...

Comment: @Harry тогда как быть? если `GetModuleHandle()` возвращает значение в 4 байта а мне надо для конкретного адреса 8?

Comment: `GetModuleHandle` на 64 битной платформе возвращает значение `HMODULE` 8 байт. Кастовать возвращаемое значение не следует, тем более используя c-style cast. `LONG_PTR` кстати тоже должен быть 64 бит на 64 битной платформе.

Comment: "...если GetModuleHandle() возвращает значение в 4 байта" - откуда вы такое взяли???

Comment: Видимо архитекторы windows приняли такое решение в целях совместимости версий своего софта. Вот IBM (вероятно заботясь о своих разработчиках) [тут](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q104610_.htm) приводит значения размеров типов данных для разных платформ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Целочисленный тип, размер которого совпадает с размером указателя, т.е. соответствует "битности" платформы, называется `std::uintptr_t` (или `std::intptr_t`).

При чем здесь вообще `long`, откуда он взялся в вашей теме и почему вы ожидаете, что `long` будет иметь 64 бита на 64-битной платформе - не ясно.

Comment: это просто моя глупость.
я был научен что `long` должен быть строго 64 бита, и, подумал что вдруг под 32-битной системой нельзя объявить переменную большего размера.
Естественно, это не так

Answer (score 1):

Используя приведенную вами функцию, доступ к памяти не получить. Вы сможете получить дескриптор (handle - фактически индекс в таблице структур в ядре) выбранного модуля (запущенного приложения или библиотеки).

Судя по всему, вы хотите вручную выделять память для своих задач. Это можно сделать например с помощью функции [VirtualAlloc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc). Однако вы неправильно представляете себе как устроена виртуальная память и адресное пространство процессов в Windows. Дело в том, что до тех пор, пока память не выделена явным образом для определенного участка адресного пространства, эти адреса фактически не будут ассоциированы ни с какой памятью. Благодаря этой особенности, возможно к примеру запускать в ОС множество процессов, каждый из которых имеет 4/64гб адресов, или же привязать адреса напрямую к диску, или куда бы то ни было еще.

Рекомендую просмотреть один из курсов по организации ОС Windows, например [этот](https://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/10471/1078/info).